# Check Array's Even Indexes For NaN Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I want to return `true` if any of the elements at **even indexes** in `arr` are **NaN**

**Examples:**

> ['5', '+', '10', '-', '30'] = `false`

> ['5', '+', '10', '-', 'num'] = `true`

My Failed Attempt:

```
let str = '5 + 5 * 10 - 7'
let arr = str.split(' ')

return arr.some(arg => isNaN(arg[i % 2 == 0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the index parameter for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let str = '5 + 5 * 10 - 7'
let arr = str.split(' ')
let res = arr.some((arg,i) => i % 2 === 0 && isNaN(arg))
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
arr.filter((_, i) => !(i % 2)).some(isNaN)
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function receives the index as an additional argument.

```
return arr.some((arg, i) => i % 2 == 0 && isNaN(arg))
```